# SQL Statement to Select the Most recent date that the sum of two columns was higher than X

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having some issues getting a sql query to select the rows I'm looking for.

I need to select the most recent date for which the sum of two columns is greater than some number X, but whenever I run the query I just get the most recent date, flat out.  Here is what I have, I'm not sure what I'm missing here:

```
SELECT
    AccountNumber,
    MAX(BalanceDate)
FROM 
    MyTable
WHERE
    BalanceType1 + BalanceType2 > X
AND
    AccountNumber IN('111111111111', '2222222222222')
GROUP BY
    AccountNumber
```

I'm not that awesome with SQL, but from what I've read it seems like this should work, but I just keep getting the most recent day period.  Right now it's returning 05/06/2014, but I've verified that based on the conditions I've given it I should be getting a return that is a few days prior.

Any ideas?

Comment: The query looks correct to me. Please show data of rows being returned and those you want to be returned

Comment: Are columns `BalanceType1` and `BalanceType2` numeric ?  Is the `BalanceDate` column a date or Datetime column, (not a character )?  also, you can't use `X` like that... It needs to be a parameter or a literal value ...  otherwise, the query looks correct

Comment: 05/06/2014 ??? Surely 2014-05-06 !!!

Comment: @Bohemian I'll update the question in a moment.  BalanceType1 and BalanceType2 are numeric, and the BalanceDate column is a datetime column I believe.  I'm not actually using X, I just did that to generalize.  The real parameter is -7.  Actually the date does return in MM/dd/yyyy format, technically MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss AM/PM format.